# How to send credentials via Url without Curl for HTTPBasicAuth, python

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication

I want to send the credentials for the @auth.login_required to access my 
other methods in my Flask Webapp with a browser.

I know with Curl is:
curl -u username:password -i http://localhost:5000/method

Some example ?

i send like this username:password@localhost:5000/method but didn´t work

Comment: Can you show your view(router) where is handled request?

Answer (score 1):

On method GET:

http://localhost:5000/method?login='mylogin'&password=123

Answer (score 0):

Typically, browsers will present you with a prompt to enter your credentials. Try simply navigating to the endpoint and see if your browser allows you to enter your credentials.